# Visual Studio 2022 not showing check-in status on Report Server Project files (e.g. .rdl)

Tags: git, reporting-services, visual-studio-2022

I'm missing the individual check-in status icons (lock, checkmark, +) for files in Visual Studio 2022 "Solution Explorer" tab when we create a Git Repository for a "Report Server Project".  The "Git Changes" tab does track the correct commit changes for these files, and sync works fine.  Any ideas?

To reproduce:  Create a new Report Server Project from the templates (obviously you'll need https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio2022)

Right click the solution and create a Git repository.  After you do, the project itself will have a lock icon, but the reports (rdl) and data set (rds) files will not.  Any saving / sync / closing /reopening of the solution does not change the appearance.

You can also create a blank solution, and in that solution create a "Report Server Project", and create a Git repository from there.  When you do, any new files you add to the blank solution (or any standard project therein) will show the check-in status per file.

[image]

What's odd is that I have a prior (VS2019 created/updated) blank solution-backed Report Server project, and in that version, I do see the individual lock status...

[image]

Does anyone know what is causing a "clean" new solution from showing the check-in status on individual .rds/.rdl files?  My next obvious step is emailing ProBIToolsFeedback@microsoft.com

Comment: Note: I was able to recreate same issue with VS2019 and its 4/2021 Reporting Services extension as well; my prior blank solution with RS project (still working/shown above) was created prior to that date.  Reply from ProBIToolsFeedback@microsoft.com: "Thanks for pointing this out. We will check it and get back to you with an update." --> I'll update this if there is an answer on their end, but if anyone here is aware of a Git related setting that affects these lock/status icons, I'm curious.

Comment: Update: MS has created a bug on their end for this / I will keep this open until I hear back  from them, or if someone has any ideas to move it along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per MS: We have checked in a fix for this, and it will be out in the next release of Reporting Services Projects for VS 2022.

Comment: The fix is already out in the latest release. You can download it from here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio2022